# Custom field in a view with a link

Tags: theming, views

I created a view listing some Articles, but displaying a custom field I added to the Article content type instead of the usually used title.

When I would display a title instead of the custom field, I could check the option to include a link together with the title. How can I do that with the custom field instead? It only offers me the option to display the custom field as a plain text, without the link checkbox.

Comment: You should find the option "Output this field as a link" under the "Rewrite Results" section of your custom field's configuration.

Comment: I only see Output this field as a **custom** link, and that forces me to include a link address and I don't know what to type in there.

Comment: By custom field you mean a field you added on your own in the Article content type? Or a Views "Global: Custom Text" or similar? This is a Drupal 7 question, right?

Comment: Yes, a field I added to the Article content type. Edited the question to include this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a configuration that should do what you need:

[image]

Hope this helps!

Comment: it's ugly to use `/node/#`, it's better to use aliases. To get the alias, you add Path as a field, and use the `[path]` token instead. That way you get `/article/hello-world` instead of `/node/#` as a link url.

Comment: @NoSssweat: I would still use the node/# internally, i.e. for the link path, it's ugly but unambiguous and persistent. Additionaly, if there is an existing alias for that internal path, it's going to be automatically used by the outcoming URL handling of Drupal. The Path alias could be a good candidate for the title attribute of the link as well as for the Text of the link.

Comment: @StefanosPetrakis lets agree to disagree.

Comment: @NoSssweat: Sure :-)